# Route pattern matches but desired action Method is not getting called - Orchard 1.7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have a set of questions each having several tags to it. Each tag is clickable and supposed to filter the questions based on it.

I have a Route for the tag:

```
new RouteDescriptor
{
     Priority = -29,
     Route = new Route(
     "questions/tagged/{tag}",
     new RouteValueDictionary {
          {"area","xxx.Intrust"},
          {"controller","Question"},
          {"action","DisplayByTag"},
          {"tag", ""}
     },
     new RouteValueDictionary {
          {"tag",@"\w*/*"}
     },
     new RouteValueDictionary{
          {"area","xxx.Intrust"}
     },
     new MvcRouteHandler())
},
```

A typical Tag url looks like this:
http://local.intrustknowsbusiness.com/lendinng/questions/tagged/minimum%20opening%20deposit

But I am always getting 404 error.

I debugged the code, but no Action method in the controller (typically I like to see **"DisplayByTag"** is being invoked) is called.

What wrong I am doing? My other Routes are working fine and corresponding methods are also getting invoked as they should.

I am completely stuck. Please help!

Comment: What action is being called?  Can you show your `RouteConfig` as well and how this route fits into it.

Comment: No action is being called! I put break points in every possible action which could be called from the Route. What is a RouteConfig? Forgive me - I am very new to Orchard! :)

Comment: The `RouteConfig` is where your routes are defined in ASP.NET MVC 4.  I didn't realize Orchard was a CMS built on ASP.NET MVC 4, sounds like it changes how you do routes so I am not sure how to answer your question without looking into Orchard more.

Comment: To be exact Orchard was built on MVC 3. Should I put the Route.cs code here?

Comment: That would probably help yes.

Comment: Did you enable the feature?

Comment: @Bertand - which feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checklist:

- Give your route a higher priority - something greater than 0 (eg. 100)
- Check if the feature your controller (and implementation of `IRouteProvider`) is in is enabled

And btw - avoid having whitespaces (encoded as `%20`) in paths. This can lead to lots of trouble. Better encode those as dashes etc.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar Great! To clarify why it worked - Orchard default routes have priorities set below 0. If yours is lower then those defaults will take precedence when looking for a match. In your case one of the defaults matched your URL first. *Rule of thumb - the more specific your route is, the higher priority it should get.*

Comment: Very nicely clarified Pitor. It would definitely help many beginners like me. Thanks!